# linq-select rows that have all the conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a search form with several dropdownlists.
You do not need to fill in all the dropdownlists for the search operation then
some of this dropdownlist can be null.
But if I leave some of these dropdownlists blank, it will not return any results.
However, if all the dropdownlists  are filled, the result will be correct
here is the code I use in my action method:

```
CurrentCourseModels = repository.SelectCourses()
.Where(x =>(( x.EducationGroupID==null || x.EducationGroupID == eID)
&& (x.CourseNameID==null|| x.CourseNameID == nID))).ToList();
```

in this code if I choose both EducationGroupID AND CourseNameID the result will be correct.
but if I only  search for EducationGroupID there will be no result.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Maybe you meant to check if eID and nID are null and not the value in the db (which should never be null, since its the key).  `(nID == null || x.CourseNameID == nID)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to only filter when there is a relevant filter value then you can compose the query over multiple statements:

```
CurrentCourseModels = repository.SelectCourses();
if (eID != default)
    CurrentCourseModels = CurrentCourseModels.Where(x => x.EducationGroupID == eID);
if (nID != default)
    CurrentCourseModels = CurrentCourseModels.Where(x => x.CourseNameID == nID);
```

Adding `Where` clauses in sequence is equivalent to using `&&` to stitch them together, which lets you put in additional clauses as necessary.